Is it possible to have a class-forcing version of the Ground Axiom?
The Ground Axiom asserts that $V$ is not a non-trivial set-forcing extension of some inner model. Many models of GA can actually be obtained by class forcing, so I wonder if it's possible to investigate if a model is a class-forcing extension of an inner model. I know that it is class-forceable that $V=L[r]$ for some real $r$, so there would probably be some counter-intuitive results.

One problem is that class grounds might not be definable.
